# Long running DBCC CHECKDB

Tags: sql-server, dbcc-checkdb

I am on SQL 2014 Standard doing offline DBCC CHECKDBs (so on a box other than production). For the most part, my process is going pretty quick but for some reason I have this small DB (6gbs) and its taking hours to do the DBCC. Last time it ran it took 9 hours. It seems to freeze at different %'s completion when checking sys.dm_exec_requests. On this same server I'm doing CHECKDBs on databases in the terabytes range without a problem. I am using the following hints in the CHECKDB at this time (and, yes, eventually I'll do full instead of physical only)

```
WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS, PHYSICAL_ONLY, TABLOCK
```

What could be messed up with this one DB that is causing it to take forever?

Comment: Have you looked to see if the `DBCC CHECKDB` request is being blocked during this time?

Comment: Do you have [filtered non-clustered index on the sparse column](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/argenis_fernandez/archive/2013/06/16/dbcc-checkdb-on-vvldb-and-latches-or-my-pain-is-your-gain.aspx) or [nonclustered indexes with computed columns](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/dbcc-checkdb-performance-and-computed-column-indexes/) ? What is the wait type associated - when it freezes -- check `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` and `sys.dm_os_latch_stats`?

Comment: I didn't even think to check for waits or blocks since it is literally the only thing running on there. And interestingly enough, it has a wait type of lock_m_s. It is being blocked by spid 47 (so system spid) that is doing a cmd of FT CRAWL. I'm guessing that is full text crawl? We do have full text indexes on this db (but we also have it on a lot of other DBs as well). Since all I'm doing here is restoring, checkdb, and then dropping the DB, how can I keep the FT crawl from running on my DBs?

Comment: Couldn't you just disable full text after the restore?

Comment: Does dbcc checkdb miss anything if I turn that off?

Comment: I can't imagine. Checkdb is checking the data and physical structures, not babysitting the full-text services. If FT corrupted your data in production, you'll find out soon enough. Catching FT corrupting your data on the test server isn't going to buy you much.

Comment: Cool, thanks! What is the tsql to turn it off? And not all databases have it, so guessing I need tsql to check if fti is even enabled first?

Comment: You don't need to check if it's enabled first. Just put this in TRY/CATCH: `EXEC [databasename].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'disable';`

Comment: Any reason you are using TABLOCK? That opens the possibility of blocking as you have indeed experienced. Without tablock a DB snapshot will be used.

Comment: From my experience, the checkdb runs faster with tablock. Plus doesn't a DB snapshot take up more storage space? I have this offline server doing the checkdbs with just enough storage space to do our largest DBs.

Comment: The snapshot takes almost no space on a write-idle database. Since the issues you have are due to blocking you should investigate this.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at that as well as Aaron's disable script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your CHECKDB operations are getting blocked by `FT CRAWL`, a reasonable solution would be to turn full-text search off for the database after it has been restored. After all, it's not as if you are using DBCC CHECKDB to validate that full-text search is doing the right thing, or that you are restoring this copy of the database in order to facilitate FT queries.

To disable full-text search for a database named `foo`:

```
IF FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled') = 1
BEGIN
  EXEC foo.dbo.sp_fulltext_database @action = 'disable';
END
```

You probably don't need the conditional since we already know FT is installed, but it's good to carry along in case this server changes or you move your restores to a different place.